# RestKit + Google Maps iOS SDK via cocoa pods strange behaviour

Tags: restkit, static-linking, cocoapods, google-maps-sdk-ios, objective-c-runtime

When using RestKit framework with Google Maps iOS SDK I get the message on console "I restkit:RKLog.m:33 RestKit logging initialized..." at the start of app. In case of using them separately I don't have such message. I get such message even if I don't use import RestKit headers anywhere in code. Probably, I should write cocoapod rule for Linking OTHER_LDFLAGS. 
My pod file:

```
platform :ios, '6.0'
pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-SDK', '~> 1.7'
pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.22.00'
```

Comment: The problem is that you get a line of output in the log and you want to turn it off?

Comment: @Wain, Exactly! I would like to control overall app lifecycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That log method is called as part of `+load` processing, so when you include RestKit it will always be shown. Any code that you run to change the log level will run after the `+load` so this won't be affected. To change it you would need to edit the RestKit code.

You will see a difference between Debug and Release builds as the default settings in RestKit are different for each (Info and Warning level respectively).

Comment: Thank you for reply. I've already found out +load method here:[link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/load). I just wonder how linker flags of google SDK is affecting RestKit even if I don't import RestKit in code. So your solution is just to ignore that behaviour?

Comment: It isn't something you need to worry about. It should also be unrelated to maps, including RestKit is enough. What linker flags are you changing for maps? `load_all`?

Comment: Finally, I came to decision just leave it and not to change linker flags generated from cocoapods. But I found out that linker flag `-framework SystemConfiguration` is somehow producing such message.